# OnNavigatedTo only gets called when using NavigationService

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

We have a MVVM app build with `Xamarin.Forms` and `Prism.Forms`. The `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` (from `INavigationAware`) only seem to get called when navigating using Prism's NavigationService.

When using the hardware backbutton or the backbutton in the appbar the `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` methods do not get called.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? When you can not rely on it, what is the use of `INavigationAware`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the current Xamarin.Forms platform: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/744

Comment: Ah, thanks! Good to read there will be a solution in a future release.